# Rich data for email

Tags: rich-snippets, google-inbox

Does rich data for emails exists?
I recently made a purchase and my Google Inbox made this view above the actual email content. (Image provided below)

Is this some rich data everyone can add to their emails?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Google services (like Gmail and Inbox) support [Google’s "Email Markup"](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/).

It makes use of the [vocabulary Schema.org](http://schema.org/), which is also supported by Google Search for their [Rich Snippets etc.](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/)

The Stack Overflow tag for questions about this is [google-schemas](/questions/tagged/google-schemas).